# Silverlight on Linux

Tags: linux, silverlight

did anyone try to view a Silverlight site on a Linux machine? afaik, there is something called mono on Linux which is a try to port .NET on Linux machines, but did one really try to use it? did it work?

Answer (score 4):

Moonlight is the mono implementation of SilverLight.  http://www.mono-project.com/Moonlight

In an interview, they said Microsoft gave them the same test suite they use on Silverlight, so the implementation is pretty good I would suppose for being a version behind http://www.hanselminutes.com/default.aspx?showID=157

Answer (score 1):

Currently Moonlight, the implementation of Silverlight on Linux, is in Beta. According to their roadmap, the final version of Moonlight 1.0 should be out on January 20, 2009. As stated by MrChrister, they're a "release behind", because we already have Silverlight 2. However, according to the same roadmap, they plan to catch up sometime next year. Until then, I don't think Silverlight on Linux is an option to consider.